# CodeIgniter, HMVC, and where to put common libraries?

Tags: php, design-patterns, codeigniter, architecture, hmvc

If I'm planning to use HMVC, should I put libraries that I think each application may use in `/system/libraries`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Sparks' way:

```
/application
/sparks
/system
```

http://getsparks.org/

Comment: What if I didn't want to use Sparks? The libraries in question are going to be built by me. I'm pretty sure that they'll be useful to the various application within the HMVC application. I think it should go in /system/libraries/ -- but this could cause problems later on when upgrading, etc.

Comment: Then, easiest way is to use "third_party" in /application folder. Read about Application "Packages" in http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/loader.html