# How to develop Codeigniter HMVC with Smarty front-end

Tags: codeigniter, smarty, hmvc, codeigniter-hmvc

New to smarty i need to create Codeigniter HMVC with smarty front-end without module expansion, smarty working fine in Normal MVC Structure.But i am confronting trouble when i create utilizing "HMVC" its giving problem please guide.

Comment: Plz explain ur problem

Comment: i have to develop project in CodeIgniter with HMVC and front end as Smarty.HMVC working fine i can able to create modules and it will performing the operations clearly.but I dont know how to use smarty in HMVC.where should i use smarty libraries, which files i should edit.

Answer (score 0):

You could try these examples here

https://github.com/Vheissu/Ci-Smarty

http://www.coolphptools.com/codeigniter-smarty

[codeigniter + hmvc + smarty or using common libraries within modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8376032/codeigniter-hmvc-smarty-or-using-common-libraries-within-modules)

[Using Smarty 3, Code Igniter 2, and HMVC together with smarty's inheritance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11111396/using-smarty-3-code-igniter-2-and-hmvc-together-with-smartys-inheritance)

You need to just Google a bit more if in doubt ask on http://forum.codeigniter.com

Comment: this i tried they using $this->parser->parse() instead of using $this->load->view().

Answer (score 0):

I'm using CI3 with HMVC. Today I found an excellent tutorial for implementing Smarty 3. It involves implementing a lot of files and will require some tweaking because it throws up template errors. However, there is a fix for this. You need to follow the initial instructions exactly.

[Working with Codeigniter HMVC-Smarty](http://www.phpclasses.org/blog/post/261-Working-with-CodeIgniter-HMVC-Framework-Smarty-Template-and-Doctrine-ORM-all-together.html)

For the fix it is in the same forum

[Clarification on some helpers](http://www.phpclasses.org/discuss/blog/PHP-Classes-blog/post/261/thread/4/page/2/)

I added a test function to make sure it really works. I'm about to test it out for template inheritance...